# Difference between from_config and from_pretrained in HuggingFace

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, distilbert

```py
num_labels = 3 if task.startswith("mnli") else 1 if task=="stsb" else 2
preconfig = DistilBertConfig(n_layers=6)
    
model1 = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_config(preconfig)
model2 = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, num_labels=num_labels)
```

I am modifying [this code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=545PP3o8IrJV) (modified code is provided above) to test DistilBERT transformer layer depth size via `from_config` since from my knowledge `from_pretrained` uses 6 layers because in the paper section 3 they said:

> we initialize the student from the teacher by taking one layer out of two

While what I want to test is various sizes of layers. To test whether both are the same, I tried running the `from_config`
with `n_layers=6` because based on the documentation [DistilBertConfig](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/distilbert#transformers.DistilBertConfig) the `n_layers` is used to determine the transformer block depth. However as I run `model1` and `model2` I found that with  SST-2 dataset, in accuracy:

- `model1` achieved only `0.8073`
- `model2` achieved `0.901`

If they both behave the same I expect the result to be somewhat similar but 10% drop is a significant drop, therefore I believe there ha to be a difference between the functions. Is there a reason behind the difference of the approach (for example `model1` has not yet applied hyperparameter search) and is there a way to make both functions behave the same? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions you described, `from_config` and `from_pretrained`, do not behave the same. For a model M, with a reference R:

- `from_config` allows you to instantiate a *blank* model, which has the same configuration (the same shape) as your model of choice: M is as R was *before training*
- `from_pretrained` allows you to load a *pretrained* model, which has already been trained on a specific dataset for a given number of epochs: M is as R *after training*.

To cite the doc, `Note: Loading a model from its configuration file does not load the model weights. It only affects the model’s configuration. Use from_pretrained() to load the model weights.`

Comment: That means I have to train the model that is created using `from_config` using the wikitext dataset then whatever the dataset i'm going to finetune the model to. Thank you!